# TestAgentInstaller service is marked as an interactive service

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I'm getting the following error in System Event Log on the VM when trying to Install Agents in Lab Center:

> The TestAgentInstaller service is marked as an interactive service.
>   However, the system is configured to not allow interactive services.
>   This service may not function properly.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx check local registry value **NoInteractiveServices** under
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows**

Also, check Windows service Interactive Services Detection - whether it's not Disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your target machine has a group policy that disalows interactive services. You may need to contact your IT department and get an exclusion.

I would assume this is a corporate wide GP.

Comment: VM is not attached to a domain